# Update changes of an Angular component that has been downgraded to AngularJS and re used in two different places

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components

I have an Angular Component that I have downgraded so it can be used in AngularJs. It is used in a pop up modal dialog, The downgrade is successful and the component is functioning as it is supposed to but the only problem is when the modal dialog is closed, these changes are not reflected in the Angular component.

Every time the component runs and also when the model dialog is opened the ngOnInit life cycle is used for async data.

in the application view the component is in angular enviroment and used like so:

```
<interaction-component [interactionComponentData] = "data"></interaction-component>
```

in the pop up model dialog it is in angularJS enviroment and used like so:

```
<interaction-component [interaction-component-data] = "data"></interaction-component>
```

Say i have an interaction button that when clicked it displays a count in the component's view, when this action is performed and the component is running in Angular it updates the count and when the model dialog is launched - the component is running in AngularJs. Becuase of the ngOnInit - the count will be updated everytime the component runs/re-runs.

Before the model dialog is launched this component has a count of 3. Modal Dialog launches the count is still 3, now i click on the component's interaction button and increment the count to 4. In the dialog I see a count of 4 but when the dialog is closed the same component in Angular still has a like count of 3.

this is what's happening:

AngularJs count 3

Angular count 3

click and increment count in modal dialog to 4

AngularJs count 4

Angular count 3

close model dialog

Angular count 3 ( this count should be 4)

Is it possible for theses changes to keep in synch so when the changes are made in Angular are reflected in AngularJS (vice versa)?

[image]

---

### From comments

> changes are applied on depending on the `toggleClick` method which does many things, increments the count, toggles like: true || false. and then communicates with the server and makes a PUT. here is an extract from the method its self:

```
toggleClick(): void { 
    this.interactionComponentData.liked = !this.interactionComponentData.liked;
    this.interactionComponentData.count = this.interactionComponentData.liked ? this.interactionComponentData.count + 1 : this.interactionComponentData.count - 1; 
}
```

> then the ngOnIt makes a request to get the changes applied using the toggleClick method.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.interactionComponentData = post.get({}, {}, endpoint); 
    //Other code for DOM use 
}
```

> what I am trying to achieve here is when the modal dialog is open, when the button in the interactionComponent is clicked, both of the component are updated. In the modal popup Dialog and outside the modal popup dialog. Please note in the modal dialog the component is downgraded, outside the modal popup dialog it is not.

Comment: With `[interactionComponentData] = "data"`  is `data` a primitive or an object?

Comment: it's an object, what baffles me is, I would have thought (Angular/AngularJs would automatically update both uses of the component but in this case it does. May be the implementation that I used does not allow this to happen

Comment: Does the code in `ngOnInit` do an assignment of a primitive? Please show the code for `ngOnInit`. And the code for the click handler of the button.

Comment: changes are applied on depending on the toggleClick method which does many things, increments the count, toggles like: true || false. and then communicates with the server and makes a PUT. here is an extract from the method its self: 

`toggleClick(): void {
      this.interactionComponentData.liked = !this.interactionComponentData.liked;
      this.interactionComponentData.count = this.interactionComponentData.liked ? this.interactionComponentData.count + 1 : this.interactionComponentData.count - 1;
    }`

Comment: then the ngOnIt makes a request to get the changes applied using the toggleClick method. 

`ngOnInit(): void { 
      this.interactionComponentData = post.get({}, {}, endpoint);
      //Other code for DOM use
    }`

what I am trying to achieve here is when the modal dialog is open, when the button in the interactionComponent is clicked, both of the component are updated. In the modal popup Dialog and outside the modal popup dialog. Please note in the modal dialog the component is downgraded, outside the modal popup dialog it is not.

Comment: The `ngOnInit` is replacing the `interactionComponentData` reference set by the one-way binding with another reference. Of course changes to the new reference are not going to change properties in the original object.